# Sorting TDictionary

Tags: delphi, generics, sorting, dictionary, delphi-xe

I'm not experienced with Generic Collections. I need to sort a TDictionary.

```
type TSearchResult = TPair<Integer,double>;

var
   target_results : TDictionary<Integer, double>;
   session_search_results : array[0..max_searches] of TArray<TSearchResult>;
```

I'm sorting using this code

```
   session_search_results[session_search_id]:= target_results.ToArray;
   TArray.Sort<TSearchResult>(session_search_results[session_search_id],
                    TComparer<TSearchResult>.Construct(
                              function(const L, R: TSearchResult): Integer
                              begin
                                 Result := Round(R.Value - L.Value);
                              end
                    ));
```

Why do I get an Access Violation with this? What am I doing wrong?

Complement:

If I iterate through the array with

```
 for i:= 0 to Length(session_search_results[session_search_id])-1 do
      MyDebug(IntToStr(session_search_results[session_search_id][i].Key)+' = value = '
            + FloatToStr(session_search_results[session_search_id][i].Value));
```

I get an output of:

```
Debug Output: ==>CoreSearchText: array length=8<== Process TestApp.exe (2536)
Debug Output: ==>100007 = value = 19,515<== Process TestApp.exe (2536)
Debug Output: ==>100003 = value = 2,4<== Process TestApp.exe (2536)
Debug Output: ==>100005 = value = 12<== Process TestApp.exe (2536)
Debug Output: ==>100008 = value = 2,4<== Process TestApp.exe (2536)
Debug Output: ==>100002 = value = 2,4<== Process TestApp.exe (2536)
Debug Output: ==>100004 = value = 2,4<== Process TestApp.exe (2536)
Debug Output: ==>100009 = value = 40,515<== Process TestApp.exe (2536)
Debug Output: ==>100001 = value = 15<== Process TestApp.exe (2536)
```

When the sort is applied, the Access Violation crashes the application. The array seems to be ok. What can be the reason? Thanks!

Comment: Are both `session_search_id`  and `core_session_search_count` pointing to a valid array index?

Comment: Sorry I've corrected that. If I don't apply the Sort the array shows the correct content.

Comment: You are not sorting a dictionary (which is not ordered by definition), but you are sorting an array. The code you showed is correct, please show the definition of `TSearchResult` and the part where you fill the dictionary. Are you sure there are no `nil` pointers in there?

Comment: type TSearchResult = TPair<Integer,double>; I'll double check if it's possible to get nil pointers in there. When I iterate and display the content of the array (before sort) it shows ok. If there was a nil in there I should get an error? This was the best approach to sort the Dictionary.

Comment: Why do you have to round `R.Value - L.Value` in your comparison function? Are you dealing with values that can differ by `<= 0.5`. If so, your comparison function is inconsistent because 1.1 would seem to be equal to 1.5 and 1.5 would seem to be equal to 1.9, but 1.9 would evaluate as greater than 1.1

Comment: @Craig: It's a valid point despite it's irrelevant for tis particular problem. The code is for a search engine and present the results in order by relevancy, so the actual order criteria is not the focus.

Comment: @MiguelE The point is that if the relevancy that you're trying to sort by is a floating point value resulting in inconsistent comparison behaviour, you are going to 'confuse' the sorting algorithm - very likely resulting in Access Violations. Try changing your function to a simple `if A < B then Result := -1 else if A > B then Result := 1 else Result := 0;`

Comment: @Craig: I've just tried it. No luck. The Access Violation still happens. Any more suggestions?

Comment: When you get an access violation, the debugger shows you where. Include that information here so that nobody has to guess about it.

Comment: Access violation at address 00722D7E in module 'TestApp.exe'. Write of address 0000000000.

Comment: @MiguelE Alas I currently don't have access to Delphi version supporting generics. I suggest adding debug output to your compare function.

Comment: Craig has made a very good point and I'm sure I had this myself at least once. You have to make sure that your sort function does satisfy the mathematical properties of a total order: it must be anti-symmetrical, transitive and total (total is always true in this case). Otherwise you'll get access violations.

Comment: @Smasher: I've tried with Craig suggested sort function. It has raised the same error. Can you suggest one?

Comment: OK, Miguel. So what line of code is that address? Doesn't the debugger show you? (You have debug DCUs enabled in the linker options, right?)

Comment: @RobKennedy This is odd... After your comment I've double checked the debug settings and the app was running under "Release Configuration". I've changed to "Debug Configuration" and the error doesn't appear. There is a linker/compiler setting that triggers this. Can you help? The configurations I'm using are the ones pre-built into Delphi XE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a codegen bug in XE (also existing in XE2) with a redeclared generic record and optimization turned on.

This program reproduces the bug:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$O+}

uses
  Generics.Collections,
  Generics.Defaults,
  SysUtils;

type
  TSearchResult = TPair<Integer, Integer>;

function Compare(const L, R: TSearchResult): Integer;
begin
  Result := R.Value - L.Value;
end;

var
  values: TArray<TSearchResult>;
begin
  try
    SetLength(values, 3);
    TArray.Sort<TSearchResult>(values, TComparer<TSearchResult>.Construct(Compare));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

I have reported it as [QC #106391](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=106391).

A possible solution is to add the {$O-} to the unit that contains the call to TArray<T>.Sort.

Comment: I've added the compiler directive and it's solved. Thank you for your help. I hope this will save time for other developers.